# Spring Boot when outer transaction commits it performs same inserts as was previously done by inner (REQUIRED_NEW) transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Profile profile;
}

@Entity
public class Profile {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @MapsId
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;
}

public class ProcessUsers {
  @Transactional
  public void processUsers() {
       List<Users> users = repo.getUsers();

       processPart.processPart(users.getPart())
  }
}

public class ProcessPart {

   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void processPart(List<User> users) { 
      users.forEach(user -> user.setProfile(new Profile(user))
      repo.saveAll(users)
   }  
}
```

I have outer transaction which loads Users from database. Then that users are splitted to parts and they go to processing in new (Requires_new) inner transaction. During this inner transaction for every user i create profile entity then save these users. When inner transaction ends it performs commit and sql inserts for new profiles and updates for already existing users. But when outer transaction ends and performs commit it does the same inserts and updates and i get unique primary key violation.

logs:

```
JpaTransactionManager  : Initiating transaction commit
JpaTransactionManager  : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(48420828<open>)]
org.hibernate.SQL         : insert into profile (user_id, another_field) values (?, ?)
org.hibernate.SQL         : update user set updated_field = ? where id=?
JpaTransactionManager     : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(48420828<open>)] after transaction


JpaTransactionManager        : Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction
JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(713565825<open>)]
org.hibernate.SQL            : insert into profile (user_id, another_field) values (?, ?)
SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.PROFILE(USER_ID)
```

I guess this is because of sessions are different (SessionImpl(48420828), SessionImpl(713565825)).

How can i prevent outer transaction from repeating sql queries?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken given that this is a bi-directional relationship you need to also set the user to the `Profile`:

```
for (User user: users) {
   Profile profile = new Profile()
   profile.setUser(user)
   user.setProfile(profile)
}
```

Comment: sorry, my "fake" code was unclear, i set user to profile too. I've edited this part.

Comment: An additional question then: why do you need `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` ?